# Redefine def by itself without evaluate

Tags: variable, definition

If I have `\csname var:\foo\endcsname`, how can I do that : `\expandafter\gdef\csname var:\foo\endcsname{\csname var:\foo\endcsname, \bar}` ?

I know I can do it with `edef` (or `xdef` for global), but in my situation I can't evaluate the variables at the definition, because they contain something like `\pageref{\tmplabel}}`

It is possible to replace a global variable by itself, without evaluate it?

Maybe with `\let` ? But I didn't success.

Thousands of thanks

Comment: Perhaps you should start by describing the problem you're trying to solve, then it is easier to provide ideas for a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want to append something to `\csname var:\foo\endcsname`.

```
\def\appendto#1#2{%
  \expandafter\gdef\csname #1\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endcsname\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\csname #1\endcsname,#2}%
}
```

Example:

```
\def\appendto#1#2{%
  \expandafter\gdef\csname #1\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endcsname
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\csname #1\endcsname,#2}%
}

\def\foo{foo}
\expandafter\def\csname var:\foo\endcsname{start}

\appendto{var:\foo}{\bar}

\expandafter\show\csname var:\foo\endcsname
```

The terminal would show

```
> \var:foo=macro:
->start,\bar .
```

The trick is to force two expansion steps of `\csname` before carrying out the `\gdef`.

Without `\expandafter`:

```
\input expl3-generic

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new_protected:Npn \dufays_append:Nn #1 #2
 {
  \tl_put_right:Nn #1 { , #2 }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \dufays_append:Nn { c }
\cs_set_eq:NN \appendto \dufays_append:cn

\ExplSyntaxOff

\def\foo{foo}
\expandafter\def\csname var:\foo\endcsname{start}

\appendto{var:\foo}{\bar}

\expandafter\show\csname var:\foo\endcsname
```

Comment: sigh, I  missed the append in the OPs example, I guess I'll delete:-)

Comment: it's a wonderful solution! i bow to so much intelligence... thanks a million. unfortunately, i realize that i asked my question wrong. I will repost a new post.