# Evaluate just one part of a definition, and not the other part

Tags: variable, definition

Let's assume we have:

```
\def\tmpnbrefpage{sometestpagetoken}
```

how can we define a `storedpageref` variable, like (in pseudo-language):

```
"storedpageref" = \pageref{\tmpnbrefpage}
```

where `tmpnbrefpage` is evaluated when defining, but note `\pageref{\tmpnbrefpage}`, that is to say, in our example, to have:

```
"storedpageref" = \pageref{sometestpagetoken}
```

If I set `\def\storedpageref{\pageref{\tmpnbrefpage}}`, when I invoke `\storedpageref` I will have the last `\tmpnbrefpage`. And if I set `\xdef\storedpageref{\pageref{\tmpnbrefpage}}`, I will have an error : `! Missing control sequence inserted. <inserted text>  \inaccessible`

the problem can be solved with this question: how can we evaluate `example` in `\def\A{here is an \example variable}` ?

The problem may seem simple to advanced minds in the mastery of tex, but I would be very grateful for your help. (my rested mind sometimes masters '\expandafter', but I must say that I stumble stupidly on this little problem, and that I have difficulty in thinking intelligently)

**EDIT**

let's assume we have `\xdef\storedpageref{\noexpand\pageref{\tmpnbrefpage}}`, how can we redefine so that : `\storedpageref = \storedpageref, \noexpand\pageref{\tmpnbrefpage}}`. In a certain way, how to add `, \noexpand\pageref{\tmpnbrefpage}}` to `\storedpageref`

it is just possible? @egreg give us ([Redefine def by itself without evaluate](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/661640/redefine-def-by-itself-without-evaluate)) a great solution to to that without evaluate `\tmpnbrefpage`, because it was the point I was trying to make. But, how can we do that with a `\xdef`, keeping `\storedpageref`, and evaluating just `\tmpnbrefpage` in `\pageref{\tmpnbrefpage}}`?

**NEW EDIT**
So, my dear saviors from the throes of tex:

I wanted to do a simple INDEX for a book.
So, here is what I did: I store the pages values into a simple variable :

```
\newcommand\setindex[1] {%
    \def\opt{#1}%
    \ifcsname index:\opt\endcsname%EXISTS
        \expandafter\xdef\csname index:\opt\endcsname{\csname index:\opt\endcsname, \thepage}%
    \else%DOES NOT EXIST
        \expandafter\xdef\csname index:\opt\endcsname{\thepage}%
    \fi%
}
```

and, simply, to call the pages:

```
\newcommand\getindex[1] {%
   \def\opt{#1}%
   \expandafter \ifx \csname index:\opt\endcsname \relax \else%
      \space {\normalfont [~\csname index:\opt\endcsname~]~}\fi%
```

}

It works nice.

BUT, `\thepage` counter give sometimes a wrong results, because the text is compiled before being displayed. So @David Carlisle give to me a great answer: to set a label, and call the reference with pageref. Which works perfectly.

So, I have wanted to modify, in an ingenuous way, `\thepage` by `\pageref{\tmplabeltoken}`. And... I don't master the consequences... In a variable, it seems difficult (for me) to understand the behavior. Any idea? GREAT THANKS :)

With `thepage`, this is simple, because we get the value at the definition. But with labels, we have to wait that the variable is printed to evaluate the `pageref`'s commands.

So, the content of the variable has to be for example: `pageref{24testpage}, pageref{89testpage}, etc.` when called in the index.

**NEW EDIT**

```
\newcounter{nbrefpage}
\newcommand\setindex[1] {%
    \stepcounter{nbrefpage}%
    \def\tmpnbrefpage{\arabic{nbrefpage}testpage}%
    \label{\tmpnbrefpage}%
    \def\opt{#1}%
    \ifcsname index:\opt\endcsname%EXISTS

    \else%DOES NOT EXIST
        \expandafter\xdef\csname index:\opt\endcsname{\noexpand\pageref{\tmpnbrefpage}}%
        \texttt{\expandafter\meaning\csname index:\opt\endcsname}
    \fi%
}
```

the first call `setindex{paris}` give

```
macro:->\pageref {1testpage}
```

but, what to set if exists ?
If we set `\expandafter\xdef\csname index:\opt\endcsname{\csname index:\opt\endcsname, a}` we get an error `! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 30. <inserted text>  \fi`

```
\noexpand\csname index:\opt\endcsname, a
```

give `macro:->\csname index:paris\endcsname , a`

and `\expandafter\noexpand\csname index:\opt\endcsname, a` give `macro:->\index:paris , a`

that is to say the variable contains itself! so, if it called, we get `! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].` ...

how can I have: `macro:->\pageref {1testpage}, a` ?

If I do like @egreg did: `\unexpanded\expandafter{\csname index:\opt\endcsname}, a` I get also `macro:->\index:paris , a` and not `macro:->\pageref {1testpage}, a` ... I don't understand why I can't solve this problem...

Comment: It can't work like this: don't pile up edits that invalidate the existing answers. Please, ask a new question where you list ***all*** the needed detaila. But why not using the standard index making facilities?

Comment: oh, yes, of course, with pleasure. thanks again.

Comment: I don't know why I don't used the standard index... I started out like this, and now I want to go all the way^^

Answer (score 1):

`\xdef\storedpageref{\noexpand\pageref{\tmpnbrefpage}}`

will expand `\tmpnbrefpage` but not `\pagref` at definition time.

Comment: Thousands of Thanks @David Carlisle. And, then, do you know how to redefine `\storedpageref` like `"storedpageref" = "storedpageref, \noexpand\pageref{\tmpnbrefpage}"` ?

Comment: you really shouldn't change the question after  answers posted, but as you have, and egreg has already answered the modified question you can give the green tick to him, he does like collecting them.

Comment: yes you're right. so I have edited my post.

Answer (score 1):

Why not stating the real problem you have? You seem to want to accumulate `\pageref` statements, where the actual label is temporarily stored in the `\tmpbrefpage`.

From `\pageref`, I guess that you're using LaTeX.

```
\newcommand*{\storedpageref}{} % initialize
\newcommand{\addtostored}{%
  \ifx\storedpageref\empty
    \xdef\storedpageref{\noexpand\pageref{\tmpbrefpage}}%
  \else
    \xdef\storedpageref{%
      \unexpanded\expandafter{\storedpageref}, %
      \noexpand\pageref{\tmpbrefpage}%
    }%
  \fi
}
```

Complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\storedpageref}{} % initialize
\newcommand{\addtostored}{%
  \ifx\storedpageref\empty
    \xdef\storedpageref{\noexpand\pageref{\tmpbrefpage}}%
  \else
    \xdef\storedpageref{%
      \unexpanded\expandafter{\storedpageref}, %
      \noexpand\pageref{\tmpbrefpage}%
    }%
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

\def\tmpbrefpage{aaa}

\addtostored

\texttt{\meaning\storedpageref}

\def\tmpbrefpage{bbb}

\addtostored

\texttt{\meaning\storedpageref}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A different implementation where you can manage any number of lists and append either the implicit value of `\tmpbrefpage` or an explicit label.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showkeys}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\newlistofrefs}{m}
 {
  \seq_new:c { g_dufays_refs_#1_seq }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\addtolistofrefs}{O{\tmpbrefpage}m}
 {
  \seq_gput_right:cx { g_dufays_refs_#2_seq } { \exp_not:N \pageref { #1 } }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\uselistofrefs}{m}
 {
  \seq_use:cn { g_dufays_refs_#1_seq } { ,~ }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newlistofrefs{main}

\begin{document}

\def\tmpbrefpage{aaa}

\addtolistofrefs{main}

\addtolistofrefs[qqq]{main}

\def\tmpbrefpage{bbb}

\addtolistofrefs{main}

\uselistofrefs{main}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I used `showkeys` in order to see that the labels are the expected ones.

Comment: it's really nice all these proposals. But I think you're right : i have to explain the real problem I have. i will do that soon. thanks again.

Comment: in my work, `\unexpanded\expandafter{\storedpageref}` doens't give `\pageref{aaa}`, but give `\storedpageref`...

Comment: @PierreDufays I guess you're not using `\xdef`.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/661685/redefine-a-definition-with-itself-without-evaluate-its-content