# Redefine a definition with itself, without evaluate its content

Tags: variable, definition, expandafter

I have this MWE :

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[TS1,T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[french]{babel}
    
    \newcounter{nbrefpage}
\newcommand\setindex[1] {%
    \stepcounter{nbrefpage}%
    \def\tmpnbrefpage{\arabic{nbrefpage}testpage}%
    \label{\tmpnbrefpage}%
    \def\opt{#1}%
    \ifcsname index:\opt\endcsname%EXISTS
        \expandafter\xdef\csname index:\opt\endcsname{%
            \unexpanded\expandafter{\csname index:\opt\endcsname}, %
            \noexpand\pageref{\tmpnbrefpage}%
        }%
        \texttt{\expandafter\meaning\csname index:\opt\endcsname}%
    \else%DOES NOT EXIST
        \expandafter\xdef\csname index:\opt\endcsname{\noexpand\pageref{\tmpnbrefpage}}%
        \texttt{\expandafter\meaning\csname index:\opt\endcsname}%
    \fi%
}
    
    \begin{document}
    
    \setindex{paris}
    
    \setindex{paris}
    
    \end{document}
```

I obtain:

```
macro:->\pageref {1testpage}
macro:->\index:paris , \pageref {2testpage}
```

while I would like to obtain:

```
macro:->\pageref {1testpage}
macro:->\pageref {1testpage} , \pageref {2testpage}
```

any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace your line

```
  \unexpanded\expandafter{\csname index:\opt\endcsname}, %
```

by line

```
  \unexpanded\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\csname index:\opt\endcsname}, %
```

You mut to have three `\expandafter`s here because you want to 1. replace `\csname ...\endcsname` to a control sequence and 2. expand this cotnrol sequence.

Moreover, you need not define `\tmpnbrefpage` nor `\opt` macros in your `\setindex`. The definition of `\setindex` should look like that:

```
\newcount\nbrefpage
\def\setindex #1{%
   \global\advance\nbrefpage by1
   \label{\the\nbrefpage testpage}%
   \ifcsname index:#1\endcsname 
      \expandafter \xdef \csname index:#1\endcsname {%
         \unexpanded \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\csname index:#1\endcsname}, %
         \noexpand\pageref{\the\nbrefpage tespage}%
      }%
   \else \expandafter \xdef \csname index:#1\endcsname {%
         \noexpand\pageref{\the\nbrefpage tespage}% 
      }%
   \fi
   {\tt \expandafter\meaning \csname index:#1\endcsname}%
}
```

Comment: <3 !! and great thanks to @egreg and David Carliste too! Thanks stackexchange! what intelligence and what generosity!

Answer (score 4):

You're missing a couple of `\expandafter` tokens: with `\x` expanding to `\foo` the code

```
\unexpanded\expandafter{\csname x\endcsname}
```

becomes

```
\unexpanded{\x}
```

and therefore `\x` with no immediate expansion.

With

```
\unexpanded\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\csname x\endcsname}
```

you first get

```
\unexpanded\expandafter{\x}
```

and then

```
\unexpanded{\foo}
```

and finally becomes `\foo` not further expandable in the `\xdef`.

There's a simpler implementation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\newcounter{nbrefpage}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\setindex}{m}
 {
  \dufays_index_set:n { #1 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\deliverindex}{m}
 {
  \dufays_index_deliver:n { #1 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \dufays_index_set:n
 {
  \seq_if_exist:cF { g_dufays_indes_#1_seq }
   {
    \seq_new:c { g_dufays_indes_#1_seq }
   }
  \refstepcounter{nbrefpage}\label{\thenbrefpage-index}
  \seq_gput_right:cx { g_dufays_indes_#1_seq } { \exp_not:N \pageref{\thenbrefpage-index} }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \dufays_index_deliver:n
 {
  #1~\seq_use:cn { g_dufays_indes_#1_seq } { ,~ }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\setindex{paris}

\deliverindex{paris}

\setindex{paris}

\deliverindex{paris}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With `\refstepcounter` you also get hyperlinks if you load `hyperref`.